# Convert character to BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I know there is quite all of posts for converting characters to integers, strings to `BigInteger`-s, `int`-s to `BigInteger`-s, ... but I just can't figure out why this does not work.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

BigInteger sum = 0;
String line = "";
while (sc.hasNext()) {
line = sc.next();
for (char character: vrstica.toCharArray()) {
    sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(Character.getNumericValue(character)));
    }
}
```

I do have `Scanner` and `BigInteger` imported. The input data is constructed of lines with numbers, like this: 7218904932283439201\n7218904932283439201 ...

If I understand correctly, addition for `BigInteger`-s should be written like this: `bigInteger1.add(bigInteger2)`, where both numbers are of type `BigInteger`. So I should convert that character of type `char` to type `int` and then convert that `int` value to `BigInteger` with method `BigInteger.valueOf()`, which takes an `int` argument.

The error I am getting is the following: `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger`

I am not seeing where I could be wrong so I would appreciate if anyone could point out my mistake.

Comment: `BigInteger sum = 0` is not legal since BigInteger is an Object.

Comment: You are wrong in not paying enough attention. The java compiler is really good in telling you what is wrong. It only takes discipline on the reader side. Meaning: read the compiler messages word by word; most important: pay attention to the line number it is pointing to. Then read the code on that line word by word. Read the error message again. Like in your example: dont assume that the problem is about characters. As the message clearly points out to the BigInteger sum = 0 line ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to assign an `int` literal to a `BigInteger` object.

```
BigInteger sum = 0;
```

Use instead the following

```
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
```